# $\int_{0}^{1}t^{^{2}}{\sqrt{1+9t^{^{2}}}}dt$ how to integrate this

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int_{0}^{1}t^{^{2}}{\sqrt{1+9t^{^{2}}}}dt$

This must be silly but I dont know what substitution must be given .tan© didnt work so what should be done. I came across this when doing line integral but not able to solve further.

Comment: Using $\tan$ should work.  It'll turn this into a [$\int \tan^m(x)\sec^n(x)\,dx$ type integral](http://www.ck12.org/book/CK-12-Calculus-Concepts/section/8.6/).

Comment: can you use $$\LaTeX$$ please?

Comment: Is there any other substitution possible

Comment: Put $3t=\tan\theta$

Comment: @Semiclassical This *can* be computed in elementary terms.

Comment: use $$t=\frac{1}{3}\cosh(x)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $\cosh(x) = 0$ doesn't have a real solution.

Comment: Partial integration with $t\cdot t\sqrt{1+9t^2}$ makes it possible too.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $\text{t}=\frac{\tan\left(\text{u}\right)}{3}$ and $\text{d}\text{t}=\frac{\sec^2\left(\text{u}\right)}{3}\space\text{d}\text{u}$:

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\text{t}^2\sqrt{1+9\text{t}^2}\space\text{d}\text{t}=\frac{1}{27}\int_0^{\arctan\left(3\right)}\tan^2\left(\text{u}\right)\sec^3\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}=$$
$$\frac{1}{27}\left\{\int_0^{\arctan\left(3\right)}\sec^5\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}-\int_0^{\arctan\left(3\right)}\sec^3\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}\right\}$$

---

Now, you can use the reduction formula:

$$\int\sec^\text{n}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{\sin\left(x\right)\sec^{\text{n}-1}\left(x\right)}{\text{n}-1}+\frac{\text{n}-2}{\text{n}-1}\int\sec^{\text{n}-2}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x$$

So, when $\text{n}=3$:

$$\int\sec^3\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{\tan(x)\sec(x)+\ln\left|\tan(x)+\sec(x)\right|}{2}+\text{C}$$